# How to flip Multidimensional array in PHP using array_flip

Tags: php, arrays

I have Multidimensional array with key value pair so I want to flip  i.e key gets to value place and values get to key place  but I am getting error

My Php code is:

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($res),'</pre>';
```

output when print_r($res):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 3
        )

)
```

getting error in output when want to flip this array:

```
array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nick  I want to flip means array value should come to its key place and key get changed to value position

Comment: Can you show in your question what you expect as output, it may be quite simple but as already pointed out it's not clear at the moment.

Comment: array_flip() does not flip array as values.  array_flip()  can only flip string and integer values.

Comment: Is this an XY Problem?  I can't see any benefit in flipping this deep data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to flip a multidimensional array where each value is an array, but according to the docs of [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

> Note that the values of array need to be valid keys, i.e. they need to
>   be either integer or string. A warning will be emitted if a value has
>   the wrong type, and the key/value pair in question will not be
>   included in the result.

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to use array_flip on each entry:

```
$a = [
    ["userid" => 1],
    ["userid" => 2],
    ["userid" => 3],
];

$a = array_map("array_flip", $a);

print_r($a);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => userid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => userid
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => userid
        )

)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/r6BGD)

Comment: thanks for your valuable time which have  solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

array_flip() does not flip array as values. array_flip() can only flip string and integer values.

You can try this:

```
 $arr = [
   [ 'userid' => 1 ],
   [ 'userid' => 2 ],
   [ 'userid' => 3 ]
];
foreach($arr as $a){
    $flipped[] = array_flip($a);
}
print_r($flipped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way

```
$arr = [
   [ 'userid' => 1, ],
   [ 'userid' => 2, ],
   [ 'userid' => 3, ]
];
array_walk($arr, function(&$val) { $val = array_flip($val); });
```